# JPA parents without children

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity named `Child` which extends another entity `Parent`.

I want a way of retrieving all `Parent` objects without any `Child` objects.

I am using Spring Data in my projects. I would also like to know if there are built-in or more appropriate ways of achieving this using Spring Data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA supports polymorphic queries. It also supports limiting results to a particular type. It can be achieved with `TYPE` operator in `WHERE` clause of a query.

```
SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE TYPE(p) = Parent
```